# Was ist die Bedeutung des Wortes "der Papiermillionär"?

Tags: meaning

Leo [hier](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=en&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=millionaire) aber `"Millionaire on paper"` bedeutet mir nichts. Reich oder nicht?

1. was bedeutet das Wort `"der Papiermillionär"`?
2. warum gibt es zwei Wörter `"der Millionär"` und `"der Papiermillionär"`?
3. warum ist die Andere nicht genug?
4. `"false-friends"`?

Comment: "Papiermillionär" ist mir nicht geläufig, und meine erste Vermutung war, dass ein Papierfabrikant, der damit Millionär wurde, gemeint sein könnte, aber es geht wohl mehr Richtung Papiertiger? Jmd. der in Wirklich nicht Millionär ist? Der zumindest nicht eine Million flüssig hat, sondern vielleicht Immobilien, die auf dem Papier eine Million wert sind, aber kaum veräußerlich?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Papiermillionär = Millionaire on Paper - Millionär auf dem Papier. Millionär, dessen Vermögen nur in Aktien steckt. Die Höhe des Vermögens ist abhängig von den aktuellen Kursen und kann bei einem Kursverfall schnell nahe null gehen. ([Quelle)](http://www.juergenkeitel.homepage.t-online.de/seite6414.htm)

Comment: Hab ich ja noch nie gehört... man lernt nie aus